# C# Selenium Web Driver cannot find TextArea by ID

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow

I'm using Selenium Web Driver in Firefox... it doesn't pick up the textarea (in Firefox).

I have many other elements on the page with ids and it has no problem finding them.

```
<textarea  class="input" style="width: 710px" name="description" id="description" rows="7"
onchange="" cols=""></textarea> 


[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "description")]
public IWebElement InputDescription { get; set; }
```

I have tried to wait for it explicitly, but that has not helped

```
new WebDriverWait(DriverContext.Driver, new TimeSpan(0,0,30)).Until((ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("description"))));

IWebElement myEl = DriverContext.Driver.FindElement(By.Id("description"));
```

The element is not in a frame.

Any idea why this does not work?

Comment: Just to eliminate possible causes, have you tried By.CssSelector or By.XPath?

Comment: Can you share the entire HTML?
Its hard to say without it.
It could be you have 2 textarea both with the ID description, which is a big NONO! :)

Comment: which exception does it return?

Comment: This is the only element on the page with that id (however there is a hidden input element with name="description"). I have tried [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "#description")] which also failed. Error is OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: Could not find element by: By.Id description

Comment: I think the fact that there is another hidden element whose name is the same as the id is messing this up. Is that possible? I tried a CSS selector which does not use the ID and it works: [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "form#form1 div:nth-child(5) table tr:nth-child(4) .input")]. However, if I include the id at all, it breaks: [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "form#form1 div.blue-box-fluid-round:nth-child(5) table tr:nth-child(4) textarea#description")]. Is this a known bug? This is a rather messy work-around and guaranteed to be extremely brittle as this page changes a lot.

Comment: Can you share the entire page html?
Just so we can see the context :)

Comment: Sorry, I can't... it's an internal page where you have to log in :-(

Comment: Try by CSS selector "textarea#description".

Comment: Thanks but no CSS selector which uses the id works... I believe this is a Firefox bug.